# C++ serial port writing/reading. Strange Behavior: Sends two bytes on startup

Tags: c++, windows, serial-port

I have a strange phenomenon using this C++ serial Port Library:
http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/CPPWindows

Before I send anything, there are two bytes (-16, -16) getting sent on init. (Serial())

In Debug-Mode I localized it at the following line:

```
 if(!SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams))
```

Has anybody an Idea, how to fix this?

Comment: what does `SetCommState()` method do?

Comment: Sadly, I don't know... It's declared in winbase.h with the following signature:  WINBASEAPI BOOL WINAPI SetCommState(HANDLE,LPDCB);

Comment: SetCommState is a Windows API that sets the baud rate and several other port parameters. I have not seen it cause any garbage output. Make sure you call it with reasonable settings in the DCB parameter and that you do not output any serial data prior to this call.